# Lager multiple sinks for different sub-applications

Tags: logging, erlang, erlang-otp, lager

So what i am trying to do is this:

Whenever a module calls ?DEBUG() OR ?INFO() OR ?WARNING() ETC (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING are macros defined as APPNAME:debug/APPNAME:info/APPNAME:warning ETC respectively) and APPNAME is also another macro which is defined as - application:get_application(), so that whenever an app's module or process calls ?DEBUG/?WARNING/?INFO the log will go to there respective app's lager sink. But i get the following error:

```
{'module could not be loaded',APPNAME HERE}
```

I don't get why i am getting this error since i have already set up the extra lager sinks in config. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Without checking the code, I cannot be sure, but it seems that you are trying to call `AppName:info/X` without the module `AppName` existing, it does not reach lager. Maybe you need to check your [code loading](https://erlang.org/doc/system_principles/system_principles.html#code_loading) strategy?

Applications are an OTP concept and modules are an erlang one, there's no requirement to have a module with the same name as its application.